# Windows DOS mkdir named current date

Tags: windows, shell, dos

In Windows 7, I want to mkdir named current date if the current date is `2014-09-14`, and the folder is named `2014-09-14`. So I write a bat file like this:

```
@echo off
set /A current_date = date /t
mkdir %current_date%
```

But it doesn't effective. Could someone give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should create the folder:

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

md "%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"
pause
```